# Is it possible to express the idea of a number bigger than any other number ($\infty$) in programming languanges?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, computer-science

I'm studying graphs and algorithms, most of the algorithms we're using (such as Prim's algorithm), have the need of a table with a symbol $\infty$. Which in some contexts mean that it is the biggest number of all - in my programming classes, whenever we needed such symbol, we've been taught to use an arbitrary large number, which wasn't general (given that we could always input values biggest than the assigned number) and the idea of a symbol that means *biggest than all of them* is a good thing. Is it possible to express this idea in programming languanges?

Comment: Your standard IEEE floating-point numbers (`float` and `double` in C-like languages) already include positive and negative infinity: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985#Positive_and_negative_infinity

Comment: Additional examples of this kind of conceptual "trick": the [big-M technique](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_M_method) in linear programming, or the [penalty method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penalty_method) in constrained optimization.

Comment: Sometimes, when only positive integers make sense, using the "invalid" value $0$ as an encoding for $\infty$ makes sense. This is in fact not too uncommon as a practice e.g. in configuration files.

Comment: I assume it depends on the language. Although, I suppose you could write "`infinity`", and in place of "`x<y`" you could write "`x<y OR y='infinity'`" (Or some variation).

Comment: I don't understand why the question is on hold, It is said in the help center that questions about **Software that mathematicians use (except Mathematica, which has its own Stack Exchange site)** are valid. I am asking about something that would help me to use software to implement these graph algorithms.

Comment: Although you could use mathematical software to implement your code, this is not really about mathematical software. This would probably be better asked on StackOverflow or the site for a given language.

Comment: @robjohn There is no clear definition of what *is really about mathematical software*. The rule is poorly constructed in the Help Center. There says that it is valid to ask about Software that mathematicians use, I can't see how this definition alone invalidate my question.

Comment: @Vÿska: There is no *rule*. I was making a suggestion about where this question might better be asked. The people who voted to close are making the same suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course this is possible. Pick one:

- Do not use any arbitrarily large number, but literally the largest number that the numerical type can express. In C#, for example, there is `int.MaxValue` and `float.MaxValue`.
- IEEE floating point numbers already have special values for $\infty$ and $-\infty$.
- Use a value that is invalid in the given context, such as $-1$ if all valid numbers are $>0$.
- If your language supports it, use a *nullable* variable and encode your special value with `null`.
- Create your own numerical type as a struct/class/record that contains two fields: the numerical value and a boolean flag for the special value.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

[Check out what Haskell has to say.](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/logfloat-0.12.1/docs/Data-Number-Transfinite.html)